# How to enable Content available key in Offline messages in QuickBlox?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, chat, quickblox

I am facing an issue with QuickBlox for offline messages.

For offline messages QuickBlox do send the push notification. But not the silent pushnotification.

To acheive silent push notification we need to have key content-available = 1 in payload. But no such key option is there in the QuickBlox offline messages.

In Testing mode of QuickBlox there is an option to add Content-available key [image]

But in offline messages there is no such key available to enable silent push notification.

[image]

So Please guide me through this to acheive silent push notification in offline messages.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such feature in QuickBlox right now. Probably we will add it in future. There is no ETA for this yet.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can find that option in the bottom of the page. But order to receive only silent push notification, i think the alert field should not be set. Right now i am receiving remote notifications and the iOS automatically shows the banner.